# Javascript Message Box close Without clicking OK button

Tags: javascript

I would like to do message box in javascriot bu the problem is is there any property that i can user whereby i have 2 button (btn1, btn2) and 2 messgae box (msg1, msg2). Is there any properties i can use in javascript whereby if user click btn1 and btn2 fast. the msg1 should appear once click ok only msg2 should appear. Is there any property in javascript can be used

Comment: Please rewrite your post. It's hard to understand

Comment: Your title and your question don't seem to have much correlation.

Comment: You need to create a module div to do so.

Comment: Where's the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="myFunction_1()">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction_2()">Button 2</button>
<script>
function myFunction_1() {
var button_1_control = confirm("Press a button 1");
   if(button_1_control)
   {
      alert("button 1");
   }
}
function myFunction_2() {
var button_2_control = confirm("Press a button 2");
   if(button_2_control)
   {
      alert("button 2");
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks.. alert working fine.. but having problem with fancy box

Comment: is there a way to do with fancy box